# How to check threads timing?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote an application which reads all lines in text files and measure times. I`m wondering what will be the time of whole block.
For example if I start 2 threads at the same time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        t[i] = new Threads(args[j], 2);
        j++;
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    System.out.println("TIME for block 1 of threads; "
            + (max(new long[]{t[0].getTime(),t[1].getTime()})));
```

Wait for them to stop processing the files and read operation times (by getTime). Is it good thinking for multithreading that in this case the time of block of threads, will be the maximum time got from thread? I think yes, because other threads will stop working by the time the thread with max time will stop.

Or maybe should I think in another way?

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis(); you can try this for total cost

Comment: Yes, I used it in my thread.

Comment: did you get whatever you were searching??

Comment: I think so, but still thinking if my output and the way I think is correct.

Comment: Take a look at JDK-level cpu time reporting per-thread: `ThreadMXBean`/ If you want this for some benchmarking, take a look at JMH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dangerous to argue about execution order when having multiple threads! E.g. If you run your code on a single core CPU, the threads will not really run in parallel, but sequentially, so the total run time for both threads is the sum of each thread's run time, not the maximum of both.

Fortunately, there is a very easy way to just measure this if you use an `ExecutorService` instead of directly using `Thread`s (btw. this is always a good advice):

```
// 1. init executor
int numberOfThreads = 2; // or any other number
int numberOfTasks = numberOfThreads; // is this true in your case?
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

// 2. execute tasks in parallel using executor
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++) {
    executor.execute(new Task()); // Task is your implementation of Runnable
}

// 3. initiate shutdown and wait until all tasks are finished
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // we won't wait forever

// 4. measure time
long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

Now, `delta` holds the total running time of your tasks. You can play around with `numberOfThreads` to see if more or less threads give different results.

**Important note: Reading from a file is not thread-safe in Java, so it is not allowed to share a `Reader` or `InputStream` between threads!**

Comment: That andswer touches what I wanted to know! Thanks You alot for this piece of contribution and useful note. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

As far as my concern You can Use System class's static methods.
You can use it in starting of the block and end of the block and subtract the later one with earlier time.
those are :

```
System.currentTimeMillis(); // The current value of the system timer, in miliseconds.
```

or

```
System.nanoTime(); //The current value of the system timer, in nanoseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
Starting of block

`long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

End of block

```
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()- startTime;
```

By this you can calculate.